# Can't bind to 'scrollStrategy' since it isn't a known property of 'ng-template'

Tags: angular, angular-material

Facing following error after run npm start command.It will execute successfully but application is not started.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BNKrN.jpg)

If 'scrollStrategy' is an Angular directive, then add 'CommonModule' to the '@NgModule.imports' of this component

Comment: what is the issue then?

Comment: This is an error

Comment: share your code where you are using `scrollStrategy` and for what purpose are you using it.

Comment: I am not using scrollStrategy anywhere...finally resolved an issue by installing @angular/cdk: 5.0.3-e20d8f0.Beta version is not working properly.

Comment: i got this error after upgrade @angular/material to 6.0.0-rc.0.In case you use it too -  It gone after upgraded to 6.0.0-rc.0

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I was also facing the same **'scrollStrategy'** issue in my project. Then i finally checked the **@angular** packages version. Then i found that the one of my angular package **'@angular/cdk'** is upper version then my other **@angular/xxx** packages. I was using Angular 5.x.x version on my project. But i was mistakenly installed **v6.x.x** version of **@angular/cdk** package. So i finally changed the version of my **angular CDK** to **5.x.x**. and my angular project is compiling perfectly.
So, You must checked the version of **'@angular/---'** packages. It should fall in same major (i.e '5'.x.x) version.

[image]